# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'. when using VotingClassifier with custom CNNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, typeerror

```
    leNetModel = mycnn()
    leNetK = KerasClassifier(build_fn=leNetModel , epochs=100, batch_size=256, verbose=0)
    leNetK._estimator_type = "classifier"
    mlpModel = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100,50), max_iter=300,activation = 'relu',solver='adam',random_state=1)
    svmModel = SVC(kernel= 'linear', C=1.0, probability=True)

    models = [('leNet', leNetK), ('mlp', mlpModel), ('svm', svmModel)]
```

The mycnn is a custom cnn, which I convert to KerasClassifier (since that's what I found online that would be a solution to a previous error that it was not of type classifier), when running the code I get the error: TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Track trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./votingClassifier.py", line 202, in <module>
    main()
  File "./votingClassifier.py", line 130, in main
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py", line 324, in fit
    return super().fit(X, transformed_y, sample_weight)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py", line 74, in fit
    self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1043, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 861, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/izabela/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 572, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/izabela/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py", line 42, in _fit_single_estimator
    estimator.fit(X, y)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 248, in fit
    return super().fit(x, y, **kwargs)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 160, in fit
    self.model = self.build_fn(
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I know the error is with leNet because if I remove leNet from my models list I get no errors.

The code for my lenet is

```
from torch.nn import Module
from torch import nn


class Model(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 10, 5)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(10, 100, 5)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(200, 100)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 25)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(25, 2) #this is for 2 labels instead of 5
        #self.fc3 = nn.Linear(25, 5) #for 5 labels
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.conv1(x)
        y = self.relu1(y)
        y = self.pool1(y)
        y = self.conv2(y)
        y = self.relu2(y)
        y = self.pool2(y)
        y = y.view(y.shape[0], -1)
        y = self.fc1(y)
        y = self.relu3(y)
        y = self.fc2(y)
        y = self.relu4(y)
        y = self.fc3(y)
        y = self.relu5(y)
        return y
```

I know that the leNet5 does work because I have used it on its own (called in the same manner as above) and have had no issues with it, I have the right imports and everything.

Tried googling it, but just can't find a solution for the Voting Ensemble and custom CNNs that I'm looking for. Any help would be really appreciated.

I know online solutions mention that there needs to be input for when forward is called, but I don't control the calling of forward from the VotingClassifier.
Or maybe I'm just not understanding how this works.

Comment: I think your way of calling `KerasClassifier` would lead to training of `leNetModel`, and `x` and `y` data are required in training, but you did not provide them.

Comment: @liginity I guess is there a better way to do it? Rather than having to package them as a KerasClassifier?

If i don't package them as a KerasClassifier I get the error ```ValueError: The estimator Model should be a classifier.``` and the only solutions I've seen to that are to wrap the model as a KerasClassifier. There aren't really examples of the VotingClassifier using custom models so I'm flying a bit blind here.

Comment: @liginity Sorry I should've included the more complete code ```models = [('leNet', leNetModel), ('mlp', mlpModel), ('svm', svmModel)]

 model = VotingClassifier(models, voting='soft')

 model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
 y_pred = model.predict(X_val)```

I do train the VOting classifier with X and Y?

Comment: @liginity Sorry for the triple ping, I think I understand more of what you're saying, My LeNet function doesn't follow the same "fit" format like Mlpclassifier and SVC do, when I trained my LeNet5 I did so doing a loop outside of it with the batch and epochs given and called it doing ```predict_y = model(train_x.float())
   loss = loss_fn(predict_y, train_label.long())
   if idx % 10 == 0:
    print('idx: {}, loss: {}'.format(idx, loss.sum().item()))
   loss.backward()
   sgd.step()```
Are you saying I should somehow get it to follow the fit format where I give it X_train and Y_train?

Comment: Well, I do not fully understand `KerasClassifier`. I think its functionality, in your way of calling the function, is similar to the training code you provided in your comment, from `predict_y` to `sgd.step()`. In some sense, I feel it is a custom `train` function, in which a model, data, epoch numbers and so on are passed in. So you might need to pass X and Y in `KerasClassifier`.